# sas hash join vs data step merge

Tags: hash, merge, sas

I have to merge three tables, each table has between 100K -200K records. This merge takes alsmost five minutes. I need help to convert the code below into a hash join. Many thanks in advance.

```
data &dsource..main_input;
   merge &dsource..sorted_swf (in=here1)
         &dsource..sorted_input2 (in=here2)
         &dsource..sorted_input9 (in=here3 );
   by control;
   if (here1) then do;
      %recode_div    

      if typec = 45 then elig_hu= '1';    
      else if (status eq '1') or ((status in ('2','3')) and (type in ('1','2','4','6','10','11'))) then elig_hu = '1';
      else if (status eq '4') then do;
         if (noint in (1,2,3,5,6)) then elig_hu = '1';
         else if (noint eq 4) or (10 <= noint <= 43) then elig_hu = '0';
      end;
      else if (status in ('2','3')) and (type in ('5','7','8','9'))           then elig_hu = '0';
      else elig_hu = '9';
      output;

      keep var1 var2 var3 var4;
   end;
run;

data want;
   set finput.input2;
   if _n_ = 1 then do;
      %create_hash(in2,control,region,"ftest5.swf");
      %create_hash(in9,control,hudadmin,"ftest5.input9");
   end;
   /*<initialize lookup variables>*/
   rc = in2.find();
   rc = in9.find();
   if rc then do;
      /*  <handle case where lookup fails>*/
   end;
   drop rc;
run;
```

Comment: If you're only keeping var1-var4 why are you bothering with the calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Grab the %create_hash() macro from [here](https://github.com/FinancialRiskGroup/SASPerformanceAnalytics/blob/master/Performance%20Analytics%20Library/macro/create_hash.sas)

The general use is

```
data want;
set have;
format <new variables to look up>;

if _n_ = 1 then do;
   %create_hash(obj,keyvar1 keyvar2 ..., lookupvar1 lookupvar2 ..., "lookup data set");
end;

<initialize lookup variables>
rc = obj.find();

if rc then do;
  <handle case where lookup fails>
end;

drop rc;
run;
```

Comment: What is the `format <new variables to look up>;` statement at the top of your example code doing?  Are you attempting to indicate that the variables should be defined before the hash is created? If so then you should use `LENGTH` or `ATTRIB` to define variables.

Comment: @Tom, why?  If the goal is defining the variable, and you don't care about labels, etc., what does `ATTRIB` buy you?  They both are processed at compile time and put the variable on the PDV.

Comment: I normally use `LENGTH` to define the variable, but you can also use `ATTRIB`.  But `FORMAT` is for attaching formats, not defining variables. How do you set the length of a character variable using a FORMAT statement? If you permanently attach a format to the character variable you can get very strange results after merging tables.  What if you want SAS to pick the format to use for displaying your numeric variables?

Comment: `FORMAT` still defines the variable if it doesn't exists.  `format blah $32.` sets the length just as well as `length blah $32.`.  I explicitly define formats in reports when printing.

Comment: Sounds like you know enough SAS not to get in trouble using FORMAT in this way, but it can confuse novice users you might think that the FORMAT statement actually is intended to define the variable type and length.

Comment: I'm trying to merge 3 datasets, and I want to keep all the vars in the keep statement, the keep vars  come from the 3 datasets im merging, the common var is control so I used that as the key.

Comment: @user601828 you just need another %create_hash() call for the second table.

Comment: Please scroll down  in the original post to see my hash code. I'm getting an error.